# Update list for jqxListBox in jQuery upon drag event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, listbox

**Problem:**

I am using jqxListBox from http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxlistbox/index.htm and I'm having problem in figuring out how to update the list once a user has reordered the items.

**Current state:**

Does not print out the updated order of items when a user has reordered the items (1st problem). Once this is done, I would like to send the current list to a PHP page (2nd problem).

**JS code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var theme = getDemoTheme();

        var data1 = ['skin', 'intelligence', 'weight', 'volume'];

        // Create a jqxListBox
        $("#listBoxA").jqxListBox({ allowDrop: true, allowDrag: true, source: data1, width: 315, height: 150, theme: theme});

        $("#listBoxA").on('dragEnd', function () {

            // Get all items.
            var items = $("#jqxWidget").jqxListBox('getItems');

            // Get selected indexes.
            var selectedIndexes = $("#jqxWidget").jqxListBox('selectedIndexes');
            var selectedItems = [];

            // Get selected items.
            for (var index in selectedIndexes) 
            {
                if (selectedIndexes[index] != -1) 
                {
                    selectedItems[index] = items[index];
                }
            }

            $("#map_canvas").val(selectedItems); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Desired output:**

When a user has changed the order of the items, the current list should then be sent as a POST variable to a PHP page.

Answer (score 1):

What about using the getSelectedItems method instead? It returns the Array of the selected items.

var items = $("#jqxListBox").jqxListBox('getSelectedItems');

Each member of that array has "label" and "value" options - where label is the item's text and value is the item's value.